# Drupal site are giving me trouble - google sends traffic to subdomain.topdomain/article

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I saw this on 2 sites that are build in drupal, 6 and 7

google send traffic to my site like this

> ```
> makexxxxxxx.alterxxxxxx(dot)org/zeveracom-xxxxx
>
> and it should be
>
> http://makexxxxxxxxxx(dot)com/zeveracom-xxxxxxxx
> ```

I tried several redirects in htaccess,could not find anything

I want all urls from subdomain.maindomain to be redirected like they should be

the subdomain files (makexxxxxxxxx(dot)com are inside the subfolder of topdomain alterxxxxxxxx(dot)org

here is the image how my urls are indexed in google, the whole site is indexed in both ways, so i get duplicate content!!!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvh3kz65lu62fr8/Capture.JPG

Comment: What does it say inside your `.htaccess` file? Have you made any changes?

Comment: no, no changes whatsoever here is my htaccess

Comment: here is htaccess  http://pastebin.com/7hyj7Lg5

Comment: I tried this and it si not working http://pastebin.com/KgfucdCe

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your sites set up, but you can remove urls in google webmaster tools. Also LOL at 'pattaya is tough' article. I spend to last few months there, and will be back soon ;)

Comment: omg my host is like bunch of donkeys, they dont know what to do at all

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe I got confused and thought you wanted to redirect a wildcard subdomain, making the subdomain the new request.
Regardless, here are two options (depending on what you want to do):

If you want to simply redirect the subdomain to the other domain, preserving the requested URI:

```
# Conditions to check for
# If HTTP_HOST
# - ends with alterxxxxxxxx.org (not case-sensitive)
#    alterxxxxxxxx\.org$ [NC]
# - AND has zero or more characters between the beginning and alterxxxxxxxx.org
#    ^(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)alterxxxxxxxx\.org$ [NC]

# Rules to apply
# If conditions are met:
# - Redirect the whole thing to the main domain, appending the requested URI to it
RewriteRule ^ http://www.makexxxxxxxxxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**OR** if you have some sort of wildcard set up and you want to make the wildcard into the actual requested URI (like I originally thought):

```
# Conditions to check for
# If HTTP_HOST:
# - ends with alterxxxxxxxx.org (not case-sensitive)
#    alterxxxxxxxx\.org$ [NC]
# - AND has at least 1 non-dot followed by a single dot before alterxxxxxxxx.org
#    ([^.]+)(\.)
# - AND (OPTIONALLY) has www. at the very beginning
#    ^(www\.)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.)alterxxxxxxxx\.org$ [NC]

# Rules to apply
# If conditions are met:
# - Leave the www. out of everything, regardless of whether it was found or not
#    %1
# - Leave the dot between the wildcard and alterxxxxxxxx.org out of everything
#    %3
# - Use the characters that come before the dot (%3) and after the optional www. (%1)
#    %2
# - Tell the browser or Google or whoever is visiting that the redirect is permanent
#    R=301
RewriteRule ^ http://www.makexxxxxxxxxx.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you for this jerdiggy but can you change the domain names, I dont want my website to be mentioned?  Can you do this please, mjust use xxxxxxx like in first post please

Comment: @user3147837 yes no problem